# tarantoolctl connpool.lua:316: attempt to index field 'configuration' (a nil value)

Tags: tarantool

i have error with starting sharding

version of tarantool and os:
`main/101/tarantoolctl C> version 1.6.8-654-ge91080f` on `ubuntu-16.04 LTS`

in configuration file
roman@zotac-pc:~$ egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*--|^$" /etc/tarantool/instances.enabled/test.lua

```
box.cfg {
    listen = 3301;
    slab_alloc_arena = 0.5;
    slab_alloc_minimal = 16;
    slab_alloc_maximal = 1048576;
    slab_alloc_factor = 1.06;
    snapshot_period = 0;
    snapshot_count = 6;
    panic_on_snap_error = true;
    panic_on_wal_error = true;
    rows_per_wal = 5000000;
    snap_io_rate_limit = nil;
    wal_mode = "none";
    wal_dir_rescan_delay = 2.0;
    io_collect_interval = nil;
    readahead = 16320;
    log_level = 5;
    logger_nonblock = true;
    too_long_threshold = 0.5;
}
local function bootstrap()
    local space = box.schema.create_space('test')
    space:create_index('primary')
    box.schema.user.grant('guest', 'read,write,execute', 'universe')
    box.schema.user.create('test', { password = 'test' })
    box.schema.user.grant('test', 'replication')
    box.schema.user.grant('test', 'read,write,execute', 'universe')
end
box.once('test-1.0', bootstrap)
local shard = require('shard')
local shards = {
    servers = {
        { uri = [[127.0.0.1:3301]]; zone = [[0]]; };
        { uri = [[127.0.0.1:3302]]; zone = [[1]]; };
    };
    login = 'test';
    password = 'test';
    redundancy = 1;
    binary = '127.0.0.1:3301';
    monitor = false;
}
shard.init(cfg)
```

roman@zotac-pc:~$
sample error in log file:

```
main/101/test I> Sharding initialization started...
main/101/test tarantoolctl:422 E> Start failed: /usr/share/tarantool/connpool.lua:316: attempt to index field 'configuration' (a nil value)
main C> entering the event loop
```

Comment: You will most likely receive more help if you were to ask your question in English. The majority of people here on Stack Overflow know English, however very few know Russian in comparison.

Comment: i translated my question to english

Answer (score 2):

in /etc/tarantool/../example.lua from ubuntu package function shard.init(cfg) need replase shard.init(shards)
below code is working fine:

```
local shard = require('shard')
local shards = {
    servers = {
        { uri = [[127.0.0.1:3301]]; zone = [[0]]; };
        { uri = [[127.0.0.1:3302]]; zone = [[1]]; };
    };
    login = 'test';
    password = 'test';
    redundancy = 1;
    binary = '127.0.0.1:3301';
    monitor = false;
}
shard.init(shards)
```

Comment: fixed in commit: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/commit/2e536f0932263338a35099dcc82a8876e357c989